# creating account throws 404 error: Page not found

Tags: customer, magento2.4, 404-page, registration

there is customer registration page where I follow this url https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-customer-image-file-upload-in-registration-account-page/ to add file upload field.

It is working fine but the problem is when I upload pdf file name with `vendor's licence.pdf` and click submit it throws  `404 error: Page not found`
[image]
if I rename file name to `vendors licence.pdf` then it went through without any error. I do not where I have to look at ? I tried to put `die()` function in `/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/createPost` controller but no luck. how can I know where is the problem which file cause it? there is no any log. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is directly due to the space or the `'` in your filename.
I would suggest to search where is your full filename and to use a method to encode the url.

Something like

```
$originalUrl = 'http://myurl\'s withspace.pdf';
$encodedUrl = urlencode($originalUrl);
```

Comment: it accepting space but not accepting single quote

Comment: my question is where to search?

Comment: well it seems to be that method no ? `    public function getCustomerLogoUrl($logoPath)
    {
        return $this->getMediaUrl() . 'customer' . $logoPath;
    }`

Comment: actually I am not using getCustomerLogoUrl function because I am using file upload only for document upload